# Redirect http to correct https

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, ssl, https

I have a question. My Joomla installation makes sure that all transfers are through https istead of http. To rewrite all http to https i use the rewrite conditions below in .htaccess. This works great, however when i go to a page, for example: http://domainname.com/page it redirects to https://domainname.com/index.php.
What i want it to do is redirecting http://domainname.com/page to https://domainname.com/page. Same goes for 'www'.
Can you please help me with the correct redirects?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

this should work forcing all to https://www.{HOST}

Comment: Incredible... that did the trick, so now everything will keep the url intact, just making sure everything is using https://.

Can you explain what caused my configuration to redirect all none https to go to the home-page?

Comment: How can i make sure it doesn't go to www. but just https://domainname ?

Comment: just remove www. from the 3rd line
`RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`